# Programmatically create and partition a VM disk for ESXi 6.7 from scratch

Tags: linux, partitioning, vmware

I have a build script that generates some partition images (`root.img`, `boot.img` etc). These can be installed on a running physical or virtual machine using `partclone`.

How can I combine these partition images into a virtual disk that can be used by a VM as a boot disk? I'm on vSphere 6.7 and I've been trying to generate a `.vmdk` file, but any VMWare-compatible format is fine.

What I've tried:

1. Generating a normal disk image (`truncate -S disk.img 100G; parted -s disk.img mklabel gpt; parted -s mkpart..; kpartx -av disk.img; partclone.ext4 -b -s root.img -t /dev/mapper/loop1p2;`) then converting it using `qemu-img convert -S 64k -o compat6 -O vmdk disk.img disk.vmdk`. This is slow due to unnecessarily copying the images twice, but could probably work with the right compatibility options.
2. Generating an image from scratch, then mounting it as a block device and writing the partition images into it.

- `qemu-img create -f vmdk -o subformat=streamOptimized test.vmdk 100G`
- `sudo modprobe nbd`
- `sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 test.vmdk`
- `sudo parted -s /dev/nbd0 mklabel gpt` (fails with `Error: Input/output error during write on /dev/nbd0`)

I find a lot of material on how to do this after the disk has already been mounted into a VMWare virtual machine, but very little on how to programmatically build these virtual disk files in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the `subformat=streamOptimized` option. VMWare docs hint that it refers to a "Stream optimized format [that] does not support random reads or writes.", so it is not suitable for a general-purpose disk. Removing the option allows `parted` to work on the vmdk file when it is mounted as a block device.